# Exporting filtered results to Excel with PHPExcel

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I'm trying to build a report page for my company. I want to export the filtered results.

I built a page with dreamweaver on localhost. The query works well and gives me the results.

I then added a form (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5326510/C74tables.php 
 lines 316-324) with 3 hidden fields and a button to go to `exportXLS.php` when clicked. I have it working but it downloads all the rows in the table.

```
SELECT * FROM satislar WHERE satis_satici LIKE v3 AND satis_tarih between v1 and v2 ORDER BY satis_tarih DESC
```

(v1, v2 and v3 are the variables in the recordset)

`exportXLS.php` https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5326510/exportXLS.php exports all the rows **not the filtered results**.

How can I get the filtered results?

Comment: Questions on SO are expected to stand alone. If you could edit your question to include some of the code (for example, lines 316-324) from your dropbox links, you are more likely to get an answer and your question will be more useful to others.

Comment: Thank you Kate, I was waiting for a guy @LWol to help me indeed and he helped finally right after I posted here. We got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change the line:

```
$SQL='SELECT cus_id, mus_musteriadi, mus_pstnno, urun_satilanurun, satis_satici, satis_tarih FROM satislar';
```

for:

```
$SQL='SELECT cus_id, mus_musteriadi, mus_pstnno, urun_satilanurun, satis_satici, satis_tarih FROM satislar WHERE satis_satici LIKE v3 AND satis_tarih between v1 and v2 ORDER BY satis_tarih DESC';
```